# Scala Spark and Twitter feed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter

I am following some code that connects to twitter and then writes out that data to a local text file. Here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "Mycode - Not going to put real one in for obvious reasons")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", "Mycode")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", "Mycode")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", "Mycode")

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(5))

  val twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

  twitterStream.saveAsTextFiles("streamouts/tweets", "txt")
  ssc.start()
  Thread.sleep(30000)
  ssc.stop(false)
```

Now, the code is not complaining about any missing references or anything. I believe I have the correct SBT dependencies.
The following code seems to run. It creates the folder structure and text files within. However, ALL of the text files are completely blank. 0kb in size.
What am i doing wrong? Anyone any ideas, as to why it look likes it is creating the output text files, but not actually writing into the files?
By the way:
I have triple checked the consumer keys, access tokens etc from the twitter app. I'm certain I have copied them over correctly.

Conor

Comment: can you see the stream data with twitterStream.print()?

Comment: Yes, I can see it with print()

Comment: When i do: twitterStream.print() . It shows a load of json on screen.

Comment: You mean?: twitterStream.saveAsTextFiles("streamouts/tweets", "txt") This creates files. But the contents of the files are empty for some reason. Perhaps i am doing this step wrong. (i'm new to scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine in your case.

**why it look likes it is creating the output text files, but not actually writing into the files?**

As per here `new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(5))`

For each interval of 5 seconds, it collects the data that are in and creates an `RDD`, So each `RDD` are written with `prefix` and `suffix` that you pass in `saveAsTextFiles`

So your files may be empty in case your `RDD` is empty otherwise look in the files that are generated inside the folder as `part-00000`, `part-00001`, `part-00002` should contain data and not in _SUCCESS and `.part-00000.crc`

I hope this helps you,

Comment: Hi, I have just run the exact same code on another computer and it works fine. I think i'll use that computer from now on. There must be something wrong with the local install on Intellij IDEA & local spark. Thanks for your help Shankar! I appreciate it

Comment: I think it's something like setting system variables on windows. The computer where it won't work on is my work computer. And it's mostly locked down, as far as permissions go.